# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Not Sliding

Tags: javascript, image, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, carousel

I ran into an interesting issue. I'm pretty sure that the answer is very simple, but I just couldn't figure it out so I thought I look for some help.

Basically, my carousel doesn't slide. It just switches image. I even tried copying the exact HTML from the bootstrap site into my own page and it still doesn't slide. In application.js, the initialization is also has no argument.

```
// carousel demo
$('#myCarousel').carousel()
```

I notice that next and prev classes are added to each item when clicking pref/next button, but it doesn't seem to do the same thing on mine. I didn't see anything wrong when I debugged either.

What am I missing? I tested this in both latest Chrome and Safari.

Comment: `Basically, my carousel doesn't slide. It just switches image.` So the carousel "is" working, just not with the slide effect?

Comment: Just to clarify, the carousel is working, but the slide effect is not there. I just figured out that you need to also include bootstrap-transition.js for any animation and make sure you add a class called "slide" on the div that is used as container for the carousel.

I can't answer my own question until 8 hours later, but this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You also have to add `bootstrap-transition` for the sliding to work, like so:

```
<script src="twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is only true when using the non-minified version of bootstrap.js. The minified one includes the transition code.

Comment: The above hint by @MichaelTeper is my winner, solved my problem. Upvoted. Deserves to be a stand-alone answer. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 24):

I was having the same issue but with bootstrap v2.0.3 (which has transition bundled in), ended up adding the slide class to the carousel div

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
```

then you just call:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 1.x - try using bootstrap 2.x - it fixed it for me

Comment: Adding the `slide` class worked for me in bootstrap 3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
```

Pls also see:
[How can I make the Bootstrap js carousel automatically cycle as soon as the page loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750816/how-can-i-make-the-boostrap-js-carousel-automatically-cycle-as-soon-as-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. It's probably something minor your missing.
http://jsfiddle.net/chapmanc/Vza6F/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do you just put that JavaScript in a `<script>` tag?

```
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000
    })​;
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

check the css files that you have included. Try and add the bootstrap.css file as well in addition to bootstrap.min.css. It worked for me .