# How to enable horizontal sliding to bootstrap carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have two samples of twitter bootstrap carousels.

Below you can find the links of sources:

> 1. [Source page](http://untame.net/2013/04/twitter-bootstrap-carousel/) (last sample). Here is a [DEMO](http://mode87.com/untame/demo/carousel/background.html).
> 2. [Source page](http://jobpixels.com/bootslider.html). Here is a [DEMO](http://jobpixels.com/bootslider/index.html).

Both of samples contains full screen background rotators. I would like to understand why this carousels has a different effects of sliding? In a first demo it's going with a fade-in/fade-out effect by automatically, but second one works like horizontal slider with a manual posibility to move slides. After reviewing HTML codes, CSS's and JScript's still it's not clear for me why they are have different ways of rotating?

The main question is: Which parameter do I need to change in a first demo to enable automatic horizontal sliding(like in 2nd sample)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these links might be help you:

[Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Not Sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660718/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-not-sliding)

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-examples.php

Comment: Thanks for your help! Very usefull links. Just have a look at demo 1, there is a custom CSS with `.carousel.item{transition: opacity 1s;}`. To enable horizontal slider this property might be like `.carousel.item{ transition: 0.4s ease-in-out left;}`