# Bootstrap carousel not sliding

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to use the Bootstrap Carousel and have been successful to some extent. I can click and change the images too. But I have got one problem. Its just not sliding! Where am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<div id="my_carousel" class="carousel slide">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target = "#my_carousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target = "#my_carousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
    <li data-target = "#my_carousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner i">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/f3.jpg" alt = "i1" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/f2.jpg" alt = "i2" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/f1.jpg" alt = "i3" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#my_carousel" data-slide = "prev">
    <span class="icon-prev left"></span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#my_carousel" data-slide = "next">
    <span class="icon-next right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

jquery:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    })
  });    
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please give us the code where you are including all your js code ?

Comment: have you include jQuery?

Comment: @danyel I have added in the edit.

Comment: Warning to readers: make sure you also add the class "slide" to the carousel div, otherwise you will experience the same symptoms (images change but are not animated). A similar problem was posted and solved (see the second comment) in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660718/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-not-sliding

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you include this script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    })
  });    
</script>
```

And even it its not working, please check whether you are calling the above script before calling the jquery. So, it should be like this:

```
<!-- Calling jquery first -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Carousel -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    })
  });    
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I did. But its just not responding.

Comment: That was the problem. I was calling the script before loading the `jquery`. Its working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Only for information purposes to future visitors: `script language="JavaScript"` is deprecated. Use `type="text/javascript` instead. Or, if you're dealing with HTML 5, there's no need to use any of them.

Comment: when I am adding boostrap.min.js in my sample very next to jquery.js and run it's not functioning. I am curious on that. i used jquery - 2.2.3v and bootstrap - 3.3.6v.

Answer (score 8):

I just recently downloaded bootstrap carousel (v3.2.0) it doesn't work with the newest version of jQuery (v1.11) because of this line:

```
if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
```

The part `$.support.transition` was for jQuery internal use and has been deprecated, removing just that should allow your code to work again.  Better yet, you could/should replace it with Modernizr's feature detection property: `Modernizr.csstransitions`.

**UPDATE:** Also jQuery v11.1 does not support `.emulateTransitionEnd`.  To solve these issues make sure you **include transition.js in your package**.  It contains the following code:

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (Shoutout: http://www.modernizr.com/)
  // ============================================================

  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }

    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
  }

  // http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions
  $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function (duration) {
    var called = false
    var $el = this
    $(this).one('bsTransitionEnd', function () { called = true })
    var callback = function () { if (!called) $($el).trigger($.support.transition.end) }
    setTimeout(callback, duration)
    return this
  }

  $(function () {
    $.support.transition = transitionEnd()

    if (!$.support.transition) return

    $.event.special.bsTransitionEnd = {
      bindType: $.support.transition.end,
      delegateType: $.support.transition.end,
      handle: function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(this)) return e.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments)
      }
    }
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Bootstrap.js` uses functions from `jQuery.js`

so you should load jQuery.js before Boostrap.js

```
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js></script>
```

> **Plugin dependencies**
>
> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other
>   plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for
>   these dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on
>   jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files).
>   Consult our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.
>
> http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Taylor's answer helped me with this problem, but instead of removing the check for $.support.transition from carousel.js, I added this little patch JS to my build to fill the gap left by jQuery:

https://gist.github.com/jonraasch/373874#file-jquery-support-transition-js

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was able to get it working by adding this snippet to my code.

```
  <script>
        $(function(){
            // Activate Carousel
            $("#myCarousel").carousel();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This question was already solved and the OP said his mistake was including jQuery after Bootstrap, so why bother answering it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the javascript. The following should be enough,

```
<div id="my_carousel" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include this link

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but if I RemoveData() and re-initialize carousel, it works like a charm

```
//Function to animate slider captions
function doAnimations(elems) {
    //Cache the animationend event in a variable
    var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

    elems.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $animationType = $this.data('animation');
        $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
            $this.removeClass($animationType);
        });
    });
}


//Variables on page load
var $myCarousel = $('#myCarousel'),
    $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

//Initialize carousel
$myCarousel.carousel();

//Animate captions in first slide on page load
doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

// --------------------------------------------------
//Pause carousel and remove data
$myCarousel.carousel('pause').removeData();

//Re-initialize carousel
$myCarousel.carousel();

//Animate captions in first slide on page load
doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

//Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event
$myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
    doAnimations($animatingElems);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check if this happens to you:

- Is the Bootstrap JS file deferred? If so, try removing the "defer"
  ie.
  `<script defer src="bootstrap.min.js">`
- Is there another slider/carousel script? Owl Carousel, for example, may interfere with Bootstrap Carousel