# Transition in bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, transition, navbar

I have a navbar in bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="barranav">
```

I tried to show and hide it with jquery with

```
$( "#barranav" ).slideDown('fast');
```

and

```
$( "#barranav" ).slideUp('fast');
```

And it works! But without any transition effect... any idea of why this occurs?

Thank you a lot

Comment: what kind of effect do you want??

Comment: i dont mind, opacity transition for example!

Comment: You should post an actual working example of the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a transition css property in your custom css:

```
#barranav { transition: all 0.5s ease; }
```

Comment: Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mdeang2/ab4phone/4/
Not sure why that wouldn't be working for you.

Comment: I know mdeang2, that is similar to what i've done, but in my case it only appears and dissapears without the transition effect, thats why i think it can be any type of conflict with bootstrap...

Comment: What version of bootstrap do you have installed? Maybe try looking at this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660718/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-not-sliding

Comment: I use the minified version of bootstrap 3.3.5 so that's not the solution :(