# slide class not found in carousel in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making an carousel in twitter bootstrap 3 but when i use the class "carousel slide" then it gives error unknown class slide. below the code which i am using. kindly guide me.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="/images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="1" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/carousel-2.jpg" alt="2" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/carousel-3.jpg" alt="3" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/CG-carousel-4.jpg" alt="4" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap js file?

Comment: yes i include bootstrap.min.js files                    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                     "~/Scripts/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"));

Comment: It is binded when the carousel initialized. Think of it as a selector purpose only. If you want carousel to slide between images add the slide class

Comment: how i add slide class and where

Comment: Your code is correct. When is it giving error? Did you initializs carousel ? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985801/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-slide-doesnt-work it seems related to your problem

Comment: @Gokhan its gives error that slide class is unknown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Code is Correct..
In my system this code working fine..

There is no definition for  class "slide" in Bootstrap 3..But without "Slide" class ,carousel images will change with out any animation effect..

Add this script in you code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

Check the Bootstrap CSS & JS Reference in you code..
and also check the order of the Reference files

**You can follow this order:-**

1. bootstrap.css
2. bootstrap-theme.css
3. jquery-1.9.1.js
4. bootstrap.js

The script block will not work with out JQ Library..So add JQ Library file correctly ..

And Ensure that the JQ file loaded before the script working..For that you can add the reference at the top of your page

Comment: Thank you! I had this issue and it was because I was including bootstrap.css after jquery. That's such an odd way to fix the issue.