# class "slide" not found in twitter bootstrap 3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question has been asked before, but did not help me.
[slide class not found in carousel in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662302/slide-class-not-found-in-carousel-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Where can I find this slide class? And if its not available, how can I get my carousel working without it?

**Current situation:** Its not showing anything on the webpage. For reference I have copied the code from here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>C-Cube</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
            <img src="1.png" alt="Chania">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="2.png" alt="Chania">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="3.png" alt="Flower">
          </div>
        </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- carousel div end -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Comment: Do you include both CSS and JS files from Twitter Bootstrap? Have you tried the example code: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel?

Comment: [see here for some 'non-plugin'carousels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640896/3d-carousel-effect-in-web-page/27690032#27690032)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code - Simply replace the content (img's and text etc)

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAGZmZgAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAFVVVQAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```